Extract type of the values of a Record-type in Typescript?
If a file defines some types like:
// lib.ts
type MySecretComplexType = 'SECRET' | false | 42 | true[]

export type MyRecordSet = Record<string, MySecretComplexType>

export function apiCall(): MyRecordSet { return { 'foo': false, 'bar': false }}

Is it possible for another file to extract the types from the MyRecordSet? For example:
// myWorker.ts
import { MyRecordSet } from 'lib'

/**
 * Worker function to act upon child values from a MyRecordSet
 */
function myWorker(inputThing: any) { // <==== How to explicitly set `inputThing`'s type?
  console.log(typeof inputThing)
}

import { MyRecordSet, apiCall } from 'lib'
import { myWorker } from 'myWorker'

const result: MyRecordSet = apiCall()

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
  console.log(`Working on ${key}...`)
  myWorker(value)
}

How can the function myWorker define the types of its inputs to "the type of the values of the Record type defined as MyRecordSet" (when MySecretComplexType is not exported from the original library file)? Specifically where myWorker is being defined in a separate file/module, so doesn't have a result object to inspect the type of, and can only go off the exported MyRecordSet type?

You can do this with a conditional type that uses infer to extract the type associated with the keys of Record<string, T>
type MySecretComplexType = 'SECRET' | false | 42 | true[];

export type MyRecordSet = Record<string, MySecretComplexType>;

// Extract MySecretComplexType from MyRecordSet
type ExtractedType<T> = T extends Record<string, infer U> ? U : never;

type ExtractedMySecretComplexType = ExtractedType<MyRecordSet>;

